# FF extension navigate back to previous site

Tags: javascript, navigation, firefox-addon, mozilla

developping a new addon for ff I encountered a problem.

I have an observer that triggers well, and in some case it should navigate back.

e.g. I'm surfing on google and then go to another site, I want the extension to navigate back to where I came from, in this case google.

I tried a few things like

```
window.history.back();
```

and

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

but then I get the error

```
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHistory.back]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://testaddon/content/script.js :: httpRequestObserver.observe :: line 41"  data: no]
```

So can anyone tell me how to navigate back with the addon, like I can do it manually withe the arrows in the top left?

Answer (score 1):

A night shift and I got it:

```
window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.history.go(0);
```